# Is there a way to export an AES key from the Python Pycryptodome module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, aes, pycryptodome

I have a project for school and it involves cryptography in Python. I need a way to export an AES key from the Pycryptodome module. I have looked at the docs but all I could find was a way to export a RSA key not an AES key. I have the generation, but I want the "user" to be able to save a key and then decrypt some data later. I obviously need a way to export the key but I cannot find a way to do so. Anyone able to help? I have found similar questions on Stackoverflow, but they are not about Python (looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763597/cryptoapi-c-interop-with-java-using-aes) one just in case even though its about Java).

Comment: I have heard of the `export_key` function but  that seems to be for RSA.

Comment: You already have the key, you supplied it to the `AES.new()` method.

Comment: Wait, so the iv is the same? Because I would also have to store the iv right, as the same iv for a given key reduces entropy.

Comment: The IV is usually stored with the encrypted data not with the key (e.g. prepended to the encrypted data).